# Metadata API to update options on custom field from managed package

Tags: managed-package, custom-field, metadata-api

I am building a managed package with several multi-select custom fields. The options for the multi-select custom field need to be populated dynamically from our external software. Is it possible to use the Metadata API to dynamically update options for a custom field that is part of a managed package?

Comment: If a picklist then yes but only with user interaction such as a configuration page or something

Comment: @Eric, no chance of doing this automatically from an external service using APIs or similar? 

Alternatively could this be done with a trigger on a custom object? For example I create a custom object then use Bulk API to add records of custom object. Could a trigger be written on Create/Update of the object to add options to custom field?

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56558/unable-to-update-metadata-picklist-values-etc-after-post-install-script-is-exe - but even that is not automatic and requires user interaction. IIRC callout cannot be made during install so that is the sticking point.